# Конвертация мак адрес в формате uint64_t в std::string

Tags: c++, строки, hex

У меня есть переменная `uint64_t mac`, например пусть `mac=828033638099` (это соответствует мак адресу 00:c0:ca:a6:9e:d3). Я хочу перевести эту переменную в строку std::string, написал для этого следующую функцию:

```
std::string mac_u64_to_s(uint64_t mac) {

    std::string str = "";
    std::stringstream stream;

    stream << std::setfill('0')
           << std::setw(2)
           << std::hex
           << ((mac >> 40) & 0xff);

    for (int i = 32; i >= 0; i= i-8){

        stream << ":"
               << std::setfill('0')
               << std::setw(2)
               << std::hex
               << ((mac >> i) & 0xff);

    }

    str = stream.str();
    return str;
}
```

Мне кажется эта функция — ужасна, хотелось бы найти более короткое и лаконичное решение.

upd.
Исправил строки:

`<< ((mac >> 40) & 0x1ff);` на `<< ((mac >> 40) & 0xff);`

`<< ((mac >> i) & 0x1ff);` на `<< ((mac >> i) & 0xff);`

Comment: Непонятно, откуда взялись такие странные смещения и маски - `40` `0x1ff`. Там же по сути должен быть один цикл из 6 итераций, на каждой из которых обрабатывается 1 байт. `stringstream` тоже не нужен

Comment: В сторону `snprintf` посмотрите.

Comment: @user7860670 , а, ну да кстати, сдвиг неправильный, спасибо!

Comment: зачем вообще сдвиг? кастани к строке)

Comment: @eri, так если я просто преобразую условным std::to_string, то в результате у меня будет std::string str="828033638099", а мне нужно именно в шестнадцатеричном представлении с двоеточиями.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так в С++20

```
string mac_u64_to_s(uint64_t mac) {
    string str;
    for(int i = 6; i-->0;
        str += format("{:02x}{}",(mac>>8*i)&0xFF,i?":":""));
    return str;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Чтоб просто вспомнить Си вариант через приведение типов (на c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <endian.h>

int main() {
  union {
    uint64_t integer;
    unsigned char byte[8];
    }  a;

  uint64_t mac = 828033638099;

  a.integer = htobe64(mac);

  char macStr [18];
  snprintf(macStr, sizeof(macStr), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
         a.byte[2], a.byte[3], a.byte[4], a.byte[5], a.byte[6], a.byte[7]);
  puts(macStr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Минус не мой, но это UB. Надо `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>` или `std::bit_cast` или `memcpy`.

Comment: в этом нет UB. обычный union и типы фиксированного размера.

Comment: См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union , начиная со слов "undefined behavior". Сравните с аналогичной статьей про С (без ++), где это разрешено: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union